# ffmpeg encoding error

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, centos

I have just finished installing ffmpeg on my centOS server using the below link:
http://www.ultratechhost.com/forums/thread-122.html -> Method 1\

phpinfo() reports that ffmpeg has been successfully installed and i also see the ffmpeg section in phpinfo.

But when I try to encode I get an error. Please try and shed some light what the problem is and what the solution could be.

### The command and the error is as follows:

> ffmpeg -i greenlantern.mov green1.flv
>   FFmpeg version 0.6.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
>     built on Dec  4 2010 15:35:31 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
>     configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
>     libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
>     libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
>     libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
>     libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
>     libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
>     libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
>     libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
>   [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1ea4e8b0]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
>   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'greenlantern.mov':
>     Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
>   Output #0, flv, to 'green1.flv':
>   Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this file DRM protected by any chance? If so, converting probably won't work.

It looks like this is a problem with the file, rather than a problem with ffmpeg.